# validating and submitting form using jquery issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to submit form using j-query, before submitting it should do some validation and in that I've validation for capcha using ajax. Everything works fine without ajax validation.

```
<form id="RegistrationForm" name="RegistrationForm" method="post" action="save.php" >
```

jquery code

```
$('#RegistrationForm').submit(function(){
//some validation goes here
if($('#captcha').val() != '')
    { 
        var captcha = $('#captcha').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'validate.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{captcha:captcha},
            success: function(data){
                if(data == 'false')
                {
                    alert('Wrong Captcha is typed!');
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                                alert('enter');
                document.getElementById("RegistrationForm").submit();   
                                return true;

                }

              }
            });
    }
});`
```

while submitting form it shows alert "enter" but form not getting submitted.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try change document.getElementById("RegistrationForm").submit();  to $('#RegistrationForm').submit();

Comment: I tried but its not working.. any other idea...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change your variable to a JSON seening how you are retreiving from a php. if thats not the solution try

```
if (data){

}else{

}
```

FYI this is not jquery validation. Jquery validation is a library set up in order to make sure the proper fields are set up correctly before submitting. What you have done is tested if the captcha is correct after submitting.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        $(function(){
            $('#RegistrationForm').submit(function(){
                if($('#captcha').val() != ''){ 
                    var captcha = $('#captcha').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'validate.php',
                        type:'POST',
                        async:false,
                        data:{captcha:captcha},
                        success: function(response){
                            if(response == 'false')
                            {
                                alert('Wrong Captcha is typed!');
                                return false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert('enter');
                                return true;

                            }

                      }
                  });
                }
            });`

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making ajax synchronous

```
 $.ajax({
        url:'validate.php',
        type:'POST',
        async: false,
        data:{captcha:captcha},
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 'false')
            {
                alert('Wrong Captcha is typed!');
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                            alert('enter');
            document.getElementById("RegistrationForm").submit();   
                            return true;

            }

          }
        });
```

Comment: what error are you getting??? if its 404 error then their is mistake in url specified...

Comment: before i see to it.. Page getting refreshed.. So i Cant see. Somehow I managed to see using firebug. It shows blank response. Other than no specific error is showing..

Comment: If you are not getting error means you have specified url properly.Echo something from your validate.php.See if response is coming back to ajax function.Also i would suggest that you create replica of this code on jsfiddle or anywhere else.if we have code in front of us we can have you in more effective way

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when the ajax request returns other value than false , every time you are again calling from submit , i think every time it calls to submit function , but could not submit successfully . because it calls submit function recursively.

try

```
$('#RegistrationForm').submit(function(){
//some validation goes here
if($('#captcha').val() != '')
    { 
        var captcha = $('#captcha').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'validate.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{captcha:captcha},
            success: function(data){
                if(data == 'false')
                {
                    alert('Wrong Captcha is typed!');
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                     alert('enter');   
                }

              }
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah! once i had this problem but now i cleared. But still I can validate using ajax. Is problem in url:'validate.php' ??